# Spring BigDecimal input

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I hava a POJO object with one BigDecimal field ***sum***.
In controller I add this POJO object as form like this:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
model.addAttribute("command", form);
```

My jsp:

```
<form:input path="sum" size="27"/>
```

In controller i add initbinder:

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new SumEditor());
```

Part of my SumEditor class:

```
@Override
   public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
         setValue(parseMoney(text));
   }
   private BigDecimal parseMoney(String str) {
         try {
                 return new BigDecimal(str);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 logger.error("error", e);
             }
         return null;
   }
```

But in JSP view I see (in input field): |**null**________|
How fix this? I need: |___________|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply override `getText` method of `SumEditor` to have it return an empty string ("") for a null value :

```
@Override
public String getAsText() {
    if (getValue == null) {
        return "";
    }
    BigDecimal val = (BigDecimal) getValue();
    return val.toStr(); // or whatever conversion you need
}
```